# insert at end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a simple function to insert at the end of a linked list on C++, but finally it only shows the first data. I can't figure what's wrong. This is the function:

```
node* Insert(node* head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new node();

        head->data = data;
        head->link = NULL;

        return head;
    }
    else {
        node* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->link;
        }

        node* temp2 = new node();

        temp2->data = data;
        temp2->link = NULL;
        (temp->link) = temp2;

        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: At `(temp->link)=temp2;`, `temp` is a null pointer (if it weren't, you'd still be spinning in the `while(temp!=NULL)` loop). So you're dereferencing a null pointer, which is UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the condition in `while` construct from:

```
while (temp!=NULL) {
    temp=temp->link;
}
```

To

```
while (temp->link!=NULL) {
    temp=temp->link;
}
```

In statement, `temp->link = temp2`, temp is a null pointer. You were dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

To append a node at the back, `temp` pointer should point to the last node of the linked list. So, in the `while` loop, you need to just stop linked list traversal when you have reached the last node, i.e, the node whose `link` member points to nothing (`has NULL`). `while (temp->link!=NULL)` will stop at the last node as last node will have `link` member pointing to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your logic by doing this:

```
void Insert(node **pnode, int data)
{
    while (*pnode) {
        pnode = &(*pnode)->link;
    }
    *pnode = new node(data, NULL);
}
```

assuming you have a `node` constructor that initializes `data` and `link` from arguments.

Instead of calling it as

```
head = Insert(head, 42);
```

you'd now do

```
Insert(&head, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node* Insert(node* head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new node();
    }
    else {
        while (head->link != NULL) {
            head = head->link;
        }
        head = head->link = new node();
    }
    head->data = data;
    head->link = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: @EmilyL. You didn't read the edit before post your comment. Sorry I try to factorize the code that why you saw a core dump in the code before I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

change while(temp!=NULL) to while(temp->link!=NULL)